# Ruby socket keep waiting for Response

Tags: ruby, sockets

I am new to Ruby programming, I am trying to build a simple echo server, but on `client.gets` it freezes. I am new to socket programming.

**server.rb**

```rb
require "socket"
require "tty/prompt"

socket = TCPServer.open("0.0.0.0", 3000)
prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

loop do
    client = socket.accept
    client.print prompt.ask("server >")
    line = client.gets # freezes here
    puts line
end

socket.close
```

**client.rb**

```rb
require "socket"
require "tty/prompt"

socket = TCPSocket.open("192.168.1.6", 3000)
prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

loop do
    socket.print prompt.ask("client >")
    puts socket.gets # freezes here
end

server.close
```

Answer (score 1):

Values you get from `prompt.ask`, they don't include newline char. And you don't add one when you print data to the socket. So `gets` waits for end-of-line marker that never arrives (hence "freezing").

Solution: use `socket.puts` instead of `socket.print` (does the same thing, but adds a newline char at the end).